# Issue in the Mapper Code in Zend Frame Work

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

```
Notice: Undefined variable: entryMessage in /var/www/Employee/application/models/EmployeeMapper.php on line 34 Fatal error: Call to a member function setEmployeeId() on a non-object in /var/www/Employee/application/models/EmployeeMapper.php on line 34
```

This is the error i am getting i try to display the entered fields , I checked the database and the fields are getting saved , I am posting the Employee Mapper .Please check the code and tell a solution , thanks in advance

```
class Application_Model_EmployeeMapper
 {
 protected $_dbTable;

 public function setDbTable($dbTable)
 {
    if (is_string($dbTable)) {
     $dbTable = new $dbTable();
   }
if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
  throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
}
$this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
return $this;
 }

 public function getDbTable()
 {
if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
  $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Employee');
}
return $this->_dbTable;
 }

 public function fetchAll()
  {
   $table = $this->getDbTable();
   $resultSet = $table->fetchAll($table->select()->order('EMPLOYEE_ID'));
   $entries   = array();
    foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
     $entry = new Application_Model_Employee();
      $entryMessage->setEmployeeId($this->$row->EMPLOYEE_ID)
       ->setFirstName($row->FIRST_NAME)
        ->setLastName($row->LAST_NAME)
        ->setEmail($row->EMAIL)
       ->setPhoneNumber($row->PHONE_NUMBER)
    ->setHireDate($row->HIRE_DATE)
    ->setJobId($row->JOB_ID)
    ->setSalary($row->SALARY);
  $entries[] = $entry; 
}
return $entries;
 }

public function save(Application_Model_Employee $employee)
{
  $data = array(
  'EMAIL'          => $employee->getEmail(),
  'FIRST_NAME'     => $employee->getFirstName(),
  'LAST_NAME'      => $employee->getLastName(),
  'PHONE_NUMBER'   => $employee->getPhoneNumber(),
  'HIRE_DATE'      => $employee->getHireDate(),
  'JOB_ID'         => $employee->getJobId(),
  'SALARY'         => $employee->getSalary(),

  );
```

Comment: ehm, you have no Object from type "EntryMessage" its called $entry? :-)

Comment: you are right , thank you , how could i oversee such a silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you're getting is very clear, you should always read and try to understand the error message that you get, it gives you solution to most of the common problems. So always make a habit of reading and understanding the error message you get. Here,

```
Notice: Undefined variable: entryMessage in /var/www/Employee/application/models/EmployeeMapper.php on line 34
```

Notice says, undefined variable; which means that your variable `$entryMessage` is not defined. And the second part of the error that you are getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setEmployeeId() on a non-object in /var/www/Employee/application/models/EmployeeMapper.php on line 34
```

is very obvious since you are trying to call `setEmployeeId()` function from `$entryMessage` which has not been defined, yet you are assuming it to be an object and using it as an object.

I am assuming that `$entryMessage` you are using should have been `$entry`

These are quite simple and are not suitable to be asked in SO actually.

Once again, my suggestion to you are,

- Always read what the error message says, it is what you are supposed to be using for debugging any bugs in the code
- If you are new to programming you should perhaps use IDE's (netbeans,
  eclipse, etc..) which actually shows the usage of variables and
  function and syntax error in your code.
- Always do your part of research and ask question only if not found or successful, and always show what you attempted. Others are there to help you but not to solve everything for you. :)

Comment: great, but these are the suggestions for your future. I saw you had similar problems in the past; these are very normal bugs and can easily be solved if you just read and follow the error message and stack trace. You might find it helpful in the future :)

Comment: or use an IDE like Netbeans, wich will tell you before you try your code :-)

Comment: We have been instructed not to use any IDE in the beginning , so i have to do everything through terminal , and thats why i am feeling the difficulty , thank you for guiding me :-)

Comment: can you  please give me the permission to ask a question on database access , please , i will post the question , it's about links not working , i.e, i am able to retrive and display the records but not able to update or delete , where may be the mistake ?

Comment: perhaps something related to foreign key? first read what the error message say. Answer might be hidden there.

Comment: I have successfully completed the application :-)